# Discriminant of some number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb Q(\beta)$ be a number field where $\beta$ is a root of $f(X)=X^3+X+1$.
How can i calculate discriminant of  $\mathbb Q(\beta)$? 
 
I only know that if $\beta $ is a root of $f(X)=X^3+X+1$ then $\beta^2$ is a root of $f(X)=X^3+2X^2+X-1$. From here i'm stuck! Any hints would help thank you very much!!

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field) for the formula (with the determinant). Just use it. There is a cubic example at the right margin and below, with $ X^3 − X^2 − 2X − 8$.

Answer (score 4):

The discriminant of $f$ is $-31$, which is square free, so $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\beta]$ and the discriminant you're looking for is $-31.$

Comment: Can you enlighten me a bit more, i dont know how you came up with $-31$

Comment: The discriminant of a polynomial of the form $x^3 + px + q$ is $-4p^3 - 27q^2$, which is in this case $-4-27=-31$.

Comment: The discriminant of $O_K$ is the $\det$ of its trace matrix, if $R$ is a subring then its discriminant (again $\det$ of its trace matrix) is $Disc(O_K)|O_K:R|^2$, thus if $Disc(R)$ is square-free then $|O_K/R|=1$ and $R=O_K$ @EvaristeGalois